# Why the results of 5^(4-4) + 9 and (5^(4-4)) + 9 are different?

Tags: python, calculation

I am very curious about the different result of two calculations in python.

```
5^(4-4) + 9 = 12

(5^(4-4)) + 9 = 14
```

Please explain the difference.

Comment: Take a look at operator precedence (order of operations) https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence. Also note `^` is the "bitwise xor" operator. You might be looking for `**` which is for raising powers

Comment: Thank you for comment. I know exactly the bitwise XOR ^. But I am still confused about two different results.

Answer (score 6):

This is a question of operator precedence.

`+` is more strongly binding than `^`.

The precedences are documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence).

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I understand the problem. 5^(4-4) + 9 = 5^9 = 12.